How to create a filter formula using indirect, different source tabs and returning non contiguous columns
I have 2 tabs containing values that are essentially the same data, but the columns are in different order across the 2 tabs.
I'm trying to figure out the syntax for creating a dynamic filter formula that can morph the resulting output so that the columns appear in the same order no matter the source of the data on the tab reference.
This google sheet has sample data and a dropdown on the "Dynamic Filter" tab builds the formula located in B2 on the same sheet. You'll notice that I'm using some trickery to build the formula on the fly by providing filter inputs via index match trickery.
Any ideas?


Added one approach to your test sheet here:
=reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(J:J,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,indirect(c&"!A:F"),Λ,choosecols(Σ,index(xmatch(B1:G1,chooserows(Σ,1)))),
 filter(Λ,choosecols(Λ,5)=switch(A2,"Vans","Passenger Van",A2))))))



tab names are added in Column_J for the formula to pickup & reference automatically


holy heck! I would've never been able to figure that out! Will dissect your approach and apply accordingly! Thank you!
